# Could not find Path

Tags: c#

I am giving path to my file which i want to read in my program like this, `path = "c:/users/abcd/desktop/read.txt"` but while debugging i found it's showing like `c://users//abcd//desktop//read.txt` which is an invalid path.

Is there something i am missing or how should i go about declaring a path.

Comment: if your strings contain backslashes (\\) instead of slashes (/), that would make sense and would be fine since you have to escape the backslash to get a literal backslash character in your string. if you have slashes and they are doubling up, you must be doing something you're not telling us about.

Comment: I recommend that you always post the actual exception in cases like these. They usually reflect the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `path = @"c:\user\abcd\desktop\read.txt"`

I haven't worked with C# for a while, but is it possible that the debugger is just showing you the escaped version of the string but the string itself is ok? Click on the magnifying glass next to the string in your debugger to show the text visualizer and see if it looks ok there.

Comment: but what about the exception which is File NOt Found, I tried this way also but still its the same exception.

Comment: i think your are right....while chehking it through cmd prompt it says The system cannot find the path specified but if i right click the file and see its path its showing the same thing. Its on my desktop

Comment: How are you using the path once you have it in a variable? Is it trying to use the path relative to the folder the program is in? Like "C:\MyProgramFolder\c:\user\abcd\desktop\read.txt"?

Answer (score 4):

I would just use:

```
@"c:\user\abcd\desktop\read.txt"
```

(note the use of the `@`). Another likely issue is permissions; does the app have *access* to user acbd's desktop? You might also look at:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)
```

and

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
```

Comment: +1 for the safer and more proper way of getting special folder paths.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that these are backslashes. This is the debugger's way of showing certain characters. A newline would show up as "\r\n", a tab as "\t", and a backslash as "\\". The string "a\b\c\d" will show up in the debugger as "a\\b\\c\\d" because that is what you have to type into code to get the actual string "a\b\c\d". When the debugger shows doubled backslashes, each \ is actually a single .

Answer (score 0):

The debugger is just showing you the escaped version of the file. I note that one of your paths contains the string "user" while the other contains "users" is the pluralization the problem?